# instead of a desired output code is printed while getting output

Tags: php

The moment I add php code I am not getting the desired output. without it I am getting the desired output. I can't find the reason behind it.. can anybody help me with this that why my code is not working as I couldn't locate a single problem behind it.

```
<?php 
//create select queries

 ?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Shout It!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1> SHOUT IT! Shoutbox</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="shouts">
        <ul>
            <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
            <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
            <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
            <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM  - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="input">
    <form method="post" action="process.php"> 
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter your Name">
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message">
    <br/>
    <input class ="shout-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Shout it Out!">
    </form>
</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is your desired output?

Comment: Is it php file? Have you changed file extension to .php?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. So it will be hard to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your list doesn't look correct. You are missing greaterthan `>` signs closing the start of the list items.

```
    <ul>
        <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
        <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
        <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
        <li class="shout" <span> 10:15PM  - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
    </ul>
```

... should be ...

```
    <ul>
        <li class="shout"> <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
        <li class="shout"> <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
        <li class="shout"> <span> 10:15PM - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
        <li class="shout"> <span> 10:15PM  - </span> Brad: Hey what are you guys upto?</li>
    </ul>
```